# NoReverseMatch no Django

Tags: python, django

Estou com um problema no Django que não consegue resolver uma url com parâmetro

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'incluirNaRota'
> with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
> ['home/incluir/(?P[^/]+)/$']

Já procurei aqui no Stack mas os problemas semelhantes não resolviam o meu.

Segue os códigos do `urls.py`, `views.py` e do `template`:

```
path('remover/<str:idCliente>/', views.removerDaRota, name='removerDaRota'),
path('incluir/<str:idCliente>/', views.incluirNaRota, name='incluirNaRota'),


def removerDaRota(request, idCliente):
    cliente = Auxiliar.objetos.filter(codigo=idCliente).first()
    cliente.incluido = False
    cliente.save()
    clientesIncluidos, clientesNaoIncluidos = getIncluidosENaoIncluidos()
    return render(request, 'nm/rotas/confirmar.html', {'clientesIncluidos': clientesIncluidos, 'clientesNaoIncluidos': clientesNaoIncluidos})


def incluirNaRota(request, idCliente):
    cliente = Auxiliar.objetos.filter(codigo=idCliente).first()
    cliente.incluido = True
    cliente.save()
    clientesIncluidos, clientesNaoIncluidos = getIncluidosENaoIncluidos()
    return render(request, 'nm/rotas/confirmar.html', {'clientesAleatorios': clientesIncluidos, 'clientesNaoIncluidos': clientesNaoIncluidos})

    {% for cliente in clientesIncluidos%}
    <li>{{cliente.codigo}} {{cliente.razao}} <a href="{% url 'nm:removerDaRota' cliente.codigo %}">Remover</a>
    <li>{{cliente.codigo}} {{cliente.razao}} <a href="{% url 'nm:incluirNaRota' cliente.codigo %}">Incluir na rota</a></li>
```

Comment: Na sua urls.py, deveria ser um inteiro,  path('<int:pk>/excluir/',  views.removerDaRota, name='removerDaRota').. os valores serão recuperados pelo numero e não por um literal. tentai alterar ai para ver, se ter erro posta o resultado.

Comment: Mudei, não resolveu :(

Comment: poderia explicar essas duas funções removerDaRota e a incluirNaRota?, seria para remover um item no banco!!! talvez possa te ajudar se falar sobre essas funções. pq eu posso ter interpretado mal esse aviso do django.

Comment: Já tentou ao invés do **render** ```return render(request, 'nm/rotas/confirmar.html``` usar o **redirect**? Provavelmente vai dar outro erro, mas acho q vc vai conseguir resolver

Comment: Perceba que o erro `Reverse for 'incluirNaRota' with arguments '('',)' ` mostra que o argumento é uma tupla com string vazia para o primeiro elemento. Sendo assim, sua url **seria** traduzida para `http://seu.dominio/incluir/` e isso não pode ser achado em seu urls.py, pois ele espera uma string após o `incluir/`. Como não estou vendo o código todo, não posso dizer se vc está passando uma lista vazia a partir de sua view ou se o problema está no template.

Comment: @PauloMarques entendiii, consegui resolver, obrigada a todos